# How to remove or hide this <p></p> when resize the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

This is an shopping-cart icon with a "cart" paragraph. When browser is resized, I want to hide or remove the "cart" paragraph and only show the shopping-cart icon. I've tried a lot of different ways but still cannot do it. I've came out three ways:
1. Use the css selector. And use the media query to hide the p element.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 body {
    background-color: lightblue;
 }
}
```

2.Use JS to remove the p element when resize the browser.

3.Also use JS to add a new icon element to take place of the origin ones.

But I don't know how exactly they can work, help me please, Thanks a lot~

Here's what I'm working on :)

```
 <p style="black:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto; onclick="myFunction()"><i class
  ="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color:black;"></i> Cart</p>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28712561/hide-element-on-window-resize

Answer (score 0):

Write a media query and give someClass to your p or by your own way to access that 
`<p>` tag.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 p.someClass {
    display:none;
 }
}
```

**Updated**
Copy below code( `<i>` tag outside `<p>` tag)

```
<p class="someClass" style="black:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto; onclick="myFunction()"></p><i class
  ="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color:black;"></i> Cart
```

Comment: sorry display:none'

Comment: @SaugatBhattarai Read her question carefully. You are missing something.

Comment: Might be I am wrong or Is he/she updated question later?

Comment: @NirajKaushal Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: @SaugatBhattarai `When browser is resized, I want to hide or remove the "cart" paragraph and only show the shopping-cart icon.` but in your code it will hide icon and text both.

Comment: @NirajKaushal I have updated my code. Check paragraph tag closing

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `Cart` text inside a `span` tag and add class `hidden-sm`  and CSS for that class as follow.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 body {
    background-color: lightblue;
 }
 .hidden-sm{
    display:none;
 }
}
```

```html
<!--Demo Purpose-->
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<p style="black:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto; onclick="myFunction()"><i class
  ="fa fa-shopping-cart" style="color:black;"></i> <span class="hidden-sm">Cart</span></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

your `p` tag containe two elements :

1. the text *Cart*
2. the `i` tag used by FontAwsome to create the pseudo elements that containe the icon

so to hide the text and keep the icon you can use simple css

see this example

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  p {
    font-size: 0 !important;/*hide the text using font-size*/
  }
  .fa.fa-shopping-cart {
    font-size: 15px; /*show the icon using font-size*/
  }
}

/* This style is used for the example */

  p {
    font-size: 0 !important;/*hide the text using font-size*/
  }
  .fa.fa-shopping-cart {
    font-size: 15px; /*show the icon using font-size*/
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<p style="black:white;font-size:14px;font-family:Roboto; onclick=" myFunction() "><i class
  ="fa fa-shopping-cart " style="color:black; "></i> Cart</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to do your task using js on resize browser and second is by css. according to me css is perfect way for this things.i am giving both solution to you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
@media (max-width:991px){.cart span{display:none}}
</head>
<body>
<p class="cart"><i class="fa fa-cart"></i><span>Cart</span><p>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function(){
var winW = $(window).width();
if(winW <= 991){
$('.cart span').hide();
}else
{
$('.cart span').show();
}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```